# How do i create a fixed length digit counter in Java?

Tags: java

how can  i create  a  simple number counter  that counts  up-to the number n,  the only problem is the  the number of digits must not change at all times ,..eg if n= 999 == (a 3 digit Number) then it would count from 001- 999  not 1 - 999 which i keep getting.i have tried using Biginterger  but BigInter one.add(one)== "1" not "001"

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
     BigInteger one= new BigInteger("001");
     BigInteger result =new BigInteger("000");

     for (int a =0;a<=999;a++)
     {   
          System.out.println(result);
          result=result.add(one);
     }
}
```

Comment: The presentation of a number as a string is separate from how the number is stored. You can choose how you display it

Comment: if i turn the number(BigInteger)   into a String object i won't be able to do any math operations on  the String,i just need it to count up thats all,....... from 100 and upwards it is easy because 100 is also a 3 digit number but i'm not sure what to do  for all  the two and one digit numbers that remain

Comment: Yes. You count with an integer. You show it as a string. These are two different things.

Comment: ohh i think i get it, do the math operation normally>>convert result to StringObject>> convert String back to BigInteger>>do the math operation again (repeat )......but  String "002" will show up as "2" in BigInteger...

Comment: No. You don’t convert back and forth. You count and when you need to show it somewhere you make a string out of it and show it. There’s no need to convert it back anywhere.

Comment: You mean  just do the normal addition  but print your result as a String?

Comment: Removed "netbeans" tag. This questions has zero to do with netbeans.

Answer (score 7):

Sami Kuhmonen has already given you the answer.

Here is how you format a String for your requirements:

```
String.format("%03d", n)
```